# Installed MySQL server but mysql command does not ask for password in the shell

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I installed the following mysql client on my server 'mysql  Ver 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))' and went through mysql_secure_installation steps and set the password as asked through this process. In the shell im logged in as root, I wonder if this has anything to do with mysql not asking for a pasword when I use put this command? Basically, i type mysql into my terminal, and I get mysql - not promting for any passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that MySQL uses socket authentication option by default for the root user.

If you want to disable it, you need to change Authentication plugin for the `root` account from "Socket authentication" to "Native MySQL authentication".

Answer (score 3):

Probably [socket authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html) where MySQL basically authenticates you if the username calling the `mysql` binary matches a known username to MySQL.

> The server-side auth_socket authentication plugin authenticates clients that connect from the local host through the Unix socket file. The plugin uses the SO_PEERCRED socket option to obtain information about the user running the client program. Thus, the plugin can be used only on systems that support the SO_PEERCRED option, such as Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely saved your credentials in the `.my.cnf` file.

Comment: how can i force mysql command to prompt for password everytime i enter my localhost mysql enviroment? if those credentials were saved in some location through mysql_secure_installtion process how do I force these into action? right now anyone to my server can access my database without using any passwords, its laughable.

Comment: After setting root password why does MYSQL still allow me to login/access mysql console without a password?

Answer (score 0):

The mysql-server package comes pre configured with a utility called `mysql_secure_installation` that is used to set up a secure starting point for MySQL server, by deleting anonymous users and allowing you to specify the desired password strength policy.

`mysql_secure_installation` is a shell script available on Unix systems, and enables you to secure the MySQL installation by enabling you to:

1. Set a password for root accounts
2. List item remove root accounts that are accessible from outside the local
   host
3. Remove anonymous-user accounts
4. Remove the test database, which by default can be accessed by
   anonymous users

Run the command below to secure MySQL after installing mysql-server.

```
$ sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

To connect to MySQL run the below command:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check in /var/log/mysql, as some package maintainers set the application so it logs there the initial password.

You should use that password, or stop the service, and start it passwordless by launching
"mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables" and then change root password with